# select records in given ids sorting order

Tags: mysql, sql

i have table lets say - `Students`,
with 5 records and id(s) are `1 to 5`, now i want to select the records - in a way that result should come like given sorting order of id column

id column should be resulted - `5,2,1,3,4`

*is there any other way to do this - then separate db calls for ids?
single db call ?*

Comment: I suggest elaborating more, if possible use another column sort_order which you can use to sort students accordingly

Comment: I don't understand 'given sorting order of id column'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess if you really want a hard-coded order, you could do something like this:

```
order by case id 
    when 5 then 0 
    when 2 then 1 
    when 1 then 2 
    when 3 then 3 
    when 4 then 4 
    else 999 
end
```

Or more simply (as @Strawberry points out in the comments):

```
order BY FIELD(id,4,3,1,2,5) desc
```

Comment: You've not heard of FIELD() then? ;-)

Comment: Link for FIELD: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_field Disclaimer* Simply linking, don't know what it does.

Comment: No, I hadn't - I'm really not a MySQL guy. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: looks gave the results but rest of the records (which i did not passed the ids)  r coming first and then this given order.

Comment: And? You didn't say what you wanted to do with them. If you want them last, `order by field(id,4,3,1,2,5) desc`. If you want them excluded, add a `where` clause.

Comment: yes i want them down side, adding DESC - pulled the Exception records down side, but sorted the passed ids in reverse order.

Comment: Read my comment again. I reversed the IDs inside the `field` call.

Comment: Updated. If this answer works for you, you can mark it as "accepted" by clicking the tick mark beside it.